# How to work out speed from distance as a float and time as a timedelta

Tags: python, timedelta

If I have a  distance in km float variable, and a timedelta variable of time, how can I work out speed in KM/H? I'm not sure how to change timedelta to hours as a float. An example would be:

```
distance = 0.966757
time = timedelta('0 days 00:01:04')
```

Having an output of around 54Kmh

Comment: What is `timedelta`? `datetime.timedelta` can't be initialized with a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert that '1:04' to seconds

```
distance = 0.966757

time = datetime.timedelta(0,64)

distance/time.total_seconds()
>>0.015105578125
```

so you have speed in distance/second

per hour, you mulitply by 3600

```
3600*distance/time.total_seconds()
>>54.380081249999996
```

thanks for the 'total_seconds' tip guys.  although , in this case i got

```
time.total_seconds() == time.seconds
>>True
```

Comment: You should use `total_seconds()`

Comment: It should indeed be **total_seconds**, since otherwise you get the seconds modulo 60.

Answer (score 1):

Use `distance / ( time.total_seconds() / 3600.0 )` (assuming distance is already in km).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to **initialize your `timedelta`** with the proper [arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=timedelta#datetime.timedelta):

```
time = timedelta(days=0,hours=0,minutes=1,seconds=4)
```

`timedelta` has a method `total_seconds()` so you fetch:

```
total_seconds = time.total_seconds()
```

By dividing by 3600, you get the number of hours:

```
hours = total_seconds/3600.0
```

(in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) it is sufficient to divide by `3600` (`int`)).

and next you calculate the speed by dividing the distance (km) by the time (hours):

```
speed = distance/hours # unit: kmph
```